# How to add a puppet module to Gepetto, when using git?

Tags: puppet, eclipse

I followed some "best practices" from [Puppet 2.7 Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849515387) and created agent - puppet master framework, with git cvs. Unfortunately, the book doesn't cover Gepetto, so I am forced to improvise that part.

I have one main git repository that contains `manifests` and `modules` folders. I want to add a custom module in the `modules`, but when doing so I encountered problems.

First of all, I cannot find anything like "master configuration" project type, which by default would contain the `manifests` and `modules` folders. So I created a bare "Puppet project" project, and created the folders manually.

Because - as I understand it - in this configuration Gepetto doesn't really know, that this project will actually hold all the modules, it doesn't provide an option to create "Puppet module project" **subproject**, which would be nested inside the "Puppet project"'s `modules` folder.

When I nest it manually (by specifying a custom location in the `New Puppet Module Project` wizard), I get an `'Auto share git projects' has encountered a problem` error:

> Unable to ignore resources
>   Attempted to beginRule: F/puppet@puppetmaster/modules/unnamed, does not match outer scope rule: MultiRule[P/mymodule]

Did anyone of you managed to get Gepetto working with modules when everything is covered by something like "master project" that encapsulates all configuration?

Comment: I have cross-posted this question with Gepetto Puppet Google group. I'll update the answer here, if I ever get one.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I've got from Thomas Hallgren:

> Geppetto does not currently support projects with nested modules in
>   them. It assumes that you have one project per module. A project
>   however, isn't the same thing as a physical location on disk so most
>   layouts can be mapped successfully to the Geppetto workspace. For the
>   use case you mention below (a Git repository with a "modules" folder)
>   I think the best way to map it is to take the following steps:
>
> 1. Open the "Git Repositories" view. You'll find it under "Window" -> "Show View" -> "Other..." -> "Git"
> 2. Add the repository in question to the view, either by appointing an existing local clone (yellow drum with a green plus sign) or by
>      cloning a remote repository (two yellow drums with a green arrow)
> 3. Expand the repository and then expand the "Working Directory" and the "modules" folder.
> 4. Right click on one of the modules and choose "Import projects...". A wizard pops up
> 5. Choose "Import as general project" and click "Finish". The project now shows up in the Project Explorer view.
> 6. Right click on the project and choose "Add Puppet Project Nature"
>
> Repeat steps 4-6 for all desired modules.
>
> You can now work with the modules individually and Geppetto will
>   recognize the projects as module projects and map them accordingly so
>   that cross references etc. works properly.
>
> To add a new module to the "modules" directory in the same Git
>   repository:
>
> 1. Right click in the Project Explorer and choose "New" -> "Project" -> "Puppet Module Project"
> 2. Enter a name for the project, leave the "Use default location" checked, and click finish
> 3. Right click on the project and choose "Team" -> "Share project".
> 4. Choose "Git" in the wizard that pops up
> 5. Click "Next" and then choose the repository in the drop down
> 6. Enter "modules" in the "Path within repository" field
> 7. Click Finish
>
> Some more information can be found in the Geppetto documentation here:
>   http://docs.puppetlabs.com/geppetto/4.0/#geppetto-and-pe
>
> Ideas on how to improve this flow are very welcome.